# solve for x; long second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can be the following differential equation be solved:
$$\frac{d^2 x}{d t^2}=4 \frac{d x}{d t} - 4x + 48(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})$$

Comment: Write it as $x''-4x'+4x=48(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})$, then this is recognizable as a second order, nonhomogenous, linear equation. Try first solving the quadratic equation $r^2-4r+4=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

The part without the $48(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})$ is solved (as per one of the comments) by
$x=(A+Bt) e^{at}$; you can find $a$ by finding the (double) root of the equation given in the comment.

Now you need to add any particular solution of 
$$
x''-4x'+4x = 48(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})
$$

Try, as an ansatz, to look for solutions of the form
$$x(t) = (px^2+qx+r)e^{2t} + (bx^2+cx+d)e^{-2t}
$$
You can actually enforce $q=r=0$ because of the results of the first step in the solution.

If one of the parameters you solve for comes out to be $\frac34$ and the other $6$ (with the other two zero), you will know you have done things right and have the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming zero initial conditions, an easy way is the Laplace transform: $L(f)(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$. Note that $L(e^{at}) = \frac{1}{s-a}$ whenever the integral exists and $L(dx/dt) = sX(s),$ where $X(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $x(t)$.

We have
$$
s^2X - 4sX + 4X = 48\left(\frac{1}{s-2} + \frac{1}{s+2}\right)
$$
or
$$
X = \frac{48}{s^2 - 4s + 4}\frac{2s}{(s-2)(s+2)} = \frac{96s}{(s-2)^3(s+2)}
$$
The solution from here is to apply partial fraction decomposition and invert the transform. You might find the table [here](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html) helpful.

Comment: I don't think it is well to spoon-feed an OP who hasn't understood that he/she has to show some preliminary work on the subject.

Comment: meh. I see it both ways. Note that I didn't give the entire answer--there's still a bit the OP has to work for themselves.

Comment: Look at 2 other previous recent and very similar questions of the OP (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2284027) and (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2266229) : no more work ; the raw question, that's all...